# Creating a total with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formulas

I'm currently trying to create a total, min, max, and average table at the bottom of the sheet. I would also like the "table" to start two cells below the last populated cell.

I am pulling in varying amounts of data which could be a single day, or as many as 100.

```
Sub max()

Dim N As Long

N = Cells(Rows.COUNT, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'Cells(N + 1, "B").Formula = "=MAX(B$13:B$44" & N & ")" <-COMMENTED OUT / THIS WORKS

Cells(N + 1, "B").Formula = "=IF(COUNT(B$13:B$44)=0,"",MAX(B$13:B$44))" & N & ")"

End Sub
```

This is what I have so far. I'm getting a 1004 error, and realize I am not calling the variable correctly. I will also need to do this across about 200 columns. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you have ***so much*** data why not summarize and use a pivottable to get min, max etc? Give a nice Tabular form view or some such?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a huge amount of data, but I wasn't sure if a pivot table was right here. The workbooks get moved around a bit, and turned into CSV often. I wasn't sure if a pivot table would mess up any of my sheets moving around making things more difficult.

Comment: I don't think so. CSV can only have one sheet so pivot would have to be on that sheet. Not an expert though.

Comment: If I could utilize them with anywhere between 3-20 sheets that would be great, but I am unsure how I would do that or if it's reasonably possible. Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Update for non-contiguous tables.

This assumes you don't have anything below or to the right of the table on the worksheet and that your table starts at B13 (headers would be row 12):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub BuildStatsTable()
    Dim lngMaxRow As Long
    Dim lngMaxCol As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim strRng As String
    Dim rngLastUsed As Range

    Set rngLastUsed = GetLastRange(Cells(13, 2))
    lngMaxCol = rngLastUsed.Column
    lngMaxRow = rngLastUsed.Row

    For lngCol = 2 To lngMaxCol
        strRng = "R13C" & lngCol & ":R" & lngMaxRow & "C" & lngCol

        Cells(lngMaxRow + 2, lngCol).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNT(" & strRng & ")=0,"""",SUM(" & strRng & "))"
        Cells(lngMaxRow + 3, lngCol).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNT(" & strRng & ")=0,"""",MIN(" & strRng & "))"
        Cells(lngMaxRow + 4, lngCol).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNT(" & strRng & ")=0,"""",MAX(" & strRng & "))"
        Cells(lngMaxRow + 5, lngCol).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNT(" & strRng & ")=0,"""",AVERAGE(" & strRng & "))"
    Next lngCol
End Sub

Private Function GetLastRange(rngTopLeft As Range) As Range
    Dim rngUsed As Range
    Dim lngMaxRow As Long
    Dim lngMaxCol As Long

    Set rngUsed = Range(rngTopLeft, rngTopLeft.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))

    lngMaxRow = rngUsed.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=rngUsed.Cells(1), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    lngMaxCol = rngUsed.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=rngUsed.Cells(1), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column

    Set GetLastRange = Cells(lngMaxRow, lngMaxCol)
End Function
```

Comment: Yes the table has to start at row 13 regardless. The only problem with this solution is that sometimes rows can have zeros or nothing in the cell, and this overwrites the cells upon the first empty cell that is in the column. Sorry that I did not mention this in the original post. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: @JSpark Updated for non-contiguous tables.

Comment: thank you! I was playing around with the xlUp and modified the function and kinda got what I needed. But you hit the nail on the head. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When trying to use VBA to create a formula, and in that formula you want to use quotes, you have to "double up":

```
Cells(N + 1, "B").Formula = "=IF(COUNT(B$13:B$44)=0,"""",MAX(B$13:B$44))" & N & ")"
```

Comment: This gives me the same error as before. The parenthesis seems to be missing on one side, and I've been moving them around but haven't solved that part yet. For instance, the parenthesis at the very end is all by itself.

Comment: @JSpark what's the formula supposed to look like? Just realized you're just adding on a row number to a formulais `B44` supposed to become `B[last row]`?

Comment: Most of the time I end up with 31 rows of data at the most (using monthly data), and that's just the most I seem to need with the data plus formatting. Figured I would get it working that way first so it is more easily read. Plus, I don't really pull more than a months worth of data. It's just a novelty to do so right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Chr(34)` to append it to the formula.

```
Cells(N + 1, "B").Formula = "=IF(COUNT(B$13:B$44)=0,"& Chr(34) & Chr(34) &",MAX(B$13:B$44))" & N & ")"
```